# C++ no matching function for call to

Tags: c++

I have .h and .cpp files that seperates class implementation and interface.

There is a problem with constructors.

My compiler says that :

```
no matching function for call to ‘polygon::polygon()
polyline::polyline(rectangle& rect)
```

And lists the candidates of polygon class. Problem is rect parameter is not a type of polygon but compiler says that you dont implement the default constructor of polygon.
But I have a function that takes the same rectangle paramete in polyline class.
It is :

```
void test(rectangle& rect)
```

Compiler doenst find any error of this test function. But in constructor, there is a error.
Information about my includes :
Inside polygon.h I include rectangle.h, inside poyline.h I include just polygon.h.

polygon.h

```
class polygon{

public:
    class Point2D{
    public:
    ...
    private:
        ..
    };
    ..
    polygon(rectangle& rect);
    ~polygon();
private:
    Point2D* _coefficients;
    int _size;
}
```

;

polyline.h

```
#ifndef POLYLINE_H_
#define POLYLINE_H_
#include "polygon.h"

class polyline
{
public: 
    polyline(rectangle& rect);
    void test(rectangle& rect);     
private:
    polygon _plyline;

};

#endif
```

polyline.cpp

```
#include "polyline.h"

polyline::polyline(rectangle& rect)
{
    //polygon tmp(rect);
    //_plyline = tmp;
}
void polyline::test(rectangle& rect)
{
    //sadas
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that reproducing the issue. We don't know the code that triggers the issue and we don't have the polygon class.

Comment: In addition to @MatthieuBrucher https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The error is obviously the initialization list:

```
polyline::polyline(rectangle& rect)
: _plyline(rest){}
```

You don't have a default constructor for your polygon, so you need to construct it properly.

Comment: Thank you it worked. but i cant understand it. Because rect is rectangle, what is the relation between polygon? for example, in polyline.cpp, when i delete #include "polygon.h" and add #include "rectangle.h" it is working. What is the difference including rectanlge by polygon.h ?

Comment: It won't work. polygon doesn't have a default constructor. You have to provide a way to construct it properly. Also your rectangle& should probably be const&.